# Distribution of universal iPhone & iPad App

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store, ipa

I have created a universal app for iPhone & iPad. I have a confusion over here. That do I need to create a single .ipa file for both iPhone and iPad or two separate files need to be created. The application has same interface and same features no difference at all.

Also if I upload a single .ipa file on Apple App Store. Then what are the required steps to make it sure that the application will be available for both iPhone & iPad on Apple App Store. (like managing the screenshots etc).

I have searched the internet but not getting an easy answer for this.

If anyone has any idea then please explain it. There might be alot of people searching for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have created a single universal app then you only need to upload one ipa. If you wish to have independed iPhone and iPad versions of your app, then you would upload two ipa's with different bundle id's.

However, with uploading a universal app the only additional requirements are that you make sure your app bundle contains properly linked xibs/storyboards for each device, proper imagery for every device you're supporting, and proper screenshots in iTunes Connect for both iPad and iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused with the same interface thing, if you mean same views, then your app will either be rejected or listed as iPhone app. When you change the app type to universal in info.plist, you don't have to do anything special, just create a single IPA and upload it. You will have to supply different images for iPad and iPhone version.

It will be automatically detected as universal app.